# Download pdf generated from base64 in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I followed some step to view a base64 generated PDF in pdf.js, and it work well. I have only one problem, i can't download it.

I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on this instruction:

```
var url = this.url.split('#')[0];
```

Actually i don't have any url, i put my b64 string in localStorage and i directly open it in viewer.js like this:

```
var b64Array=new Uint8Array(base64DecToArr(localStorage['pdf'])); 
var int8View = b64Array;
```

So i access the viewer by the standart url with no params: /pdfjs/web/viewer.html

There is a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: This bug will be fixed after https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/5083 is merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who can't wait, i get an answer on the official pdfjs github.

Here is the copy/paste answer:

> I see `DEFAULT_URL` is not designed to hold array.
>   Possible solutions for PDFView.open if array is used:
>   Disable download button; 
>   Or, provide fake `this.uri`, e.g. 'document.pdf'

So, to allow download, we just need to put a value on `this.url`.